# Fblah's tools in Blender 2.92

Tags: shape-keys, tools

I've successfully downloaded and installed the [Shape Key Tools by Ajit Christopher D'Monte](https://github.com/fblah/ShapeKeyTransferBlender/tree/Blender28) into Blender 2.92. The tools menu shows up in the right margin as it should.

There should however also be a menu called Fblah's tools that I cannot locate. In some cases addons put their tools in different places such as *Add menu* but I can't even find a reference to it there. Does anybody know where to find this menu?

EDIT 1: This is what my tools-menu looks like.

[image]

EDIT 2: Still not really there - the "copy inverted bones rotation"-button is missing.

[image: Image of the updated plugin - still not really working.]

Comment: Looks as if it may not have been updated for version 2.9 according to the readme.md doc. It's a third-party addon so best to contact the author.

Comment: Ahh. Funny since it seems to be his own creation. I'll pass him a note asking where that menu is. If I get an anser I could post it here for others to know too. Thank you for your quick response John. :)

Comment: The addon seems to be broken on the latest version of Blender 2.93. I have been using Blender 2.92 and it works there. I am looking for a solution to the problem. Other addons also seem to have broken with this update. The issue is with the mesh picker and list box, I'm looking through the Blender documentation to update the code but can't find any leads yet for a fix.
You can get 2.92 here: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.92/

Comment: Please let us know whenever you find a solution so I can download an update of the add-on. :)

Comment: It has been updated. Please check and let me know if the issues have been resolved.
https://github.com/fblah/ShapeKeyTransferBlender

Comment: Great work. We're still not really there - I can't copy inverted bone rotations since that button is not there. :) Please have a look at the screen dump in my updated question.

Comment: The button will be visible once you pick a destination mesh. Here is a tutorial video with example use cases: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zBlaedkkVs

Comment: Hey again. I don't know if we are talking about the same thing. The entire fBlah's tools is missing. No buttons related to that tool is even there as you can see in my screenshots. Only the shape key tools are there but no fBlah.

Comment: Is it possible for you to join my discord and screenshare the issue? The link is in the github.

Comment: I've tried to enter the Discord but I can't sign in. I reach a "Whoops - we can't sign in". Can I email my screenshots?

Comment: I just figured out what is wrong here. These are TWO different tools. I thougt it was part of the Shape Key Tools but i's not. It's a stand-alone add-on called Fblah's tools. Here's the Git: https://github.com/fblah/fBlahTools/tree/Blender293. Unfortunately I still can't get the buttons to show even though I've installed this add-on in Blender 2.93. Is this add-on broken?

Comment: Yes thats a separate addon and it is upto date. Can you send me an email with the screenshots? Also I don't know how to use blender 2.93 I find the interface a bit confusing so I still use 2.79. In blender 2.79 and 2.8 you have to be in Object Mode to be able to access the tool.

Comment: Regardless of being in Object view or not it’s still not showing up. I just sent you an email with a screenshot of my Blender workspace to explain what I’m seeing (or rather what I’m not seeing) 

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I haven't had the time to update this plugin to version 2.92 yet but I can confirm that the version built for 2.8 works fine on Blender 2.92. The menu will show up under the **Tools** tab. Press **N** on the keyboard to show it.

[image]

Comment: I've updated my question with a screenshot of my tools-menu since what is seen in your screenshot is not what I see in mine. Have I missed a setting?